# Gridbag Background image

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, layout

I currently have a JFrame which has many different swing components such as JButtons and JLabels on it. Is it possible for me to add a background image and keep the buttons in front of the image? I have looked for other examples but they dont work for my gridbag layout for some reason

```
        package Test1;

    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Component;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
    import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
    import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class test {



private static JFrame SplashScreen;
private static JButton button1;
private JLabel splashImage;



private GridBagLayout frameLayout;
private GridBagConstraints constraints;

//method that add components to the jframe
private void addComponent( JFrame SplashScreen, Component component, int row, int column, int width, int height)
{
    constraints.gridx = column; //set gridx
    constraints.gridy = row; //set gridy
    constraints.gridwidth = width; //set gridwidth
    constraints.gridheight = height; //set gridheight
    frameLayout.setConstraints( component, constraints); //set constraints
    SplashScreen.getContentPane().add(component); //add component
}

public test() {


    SplashScreen = new JFrame("SplashScreen");
    frameLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    SplashScreen.getContentPane().setLayout(frameLayout);

    constraints.weightx = 1; //can grow taller
    constraints.weighty = 1; //can grow wider

    button1 = new JButton("This is a button");  
    addComponent(SplashScreen, button1, 1, 1, 1, 1); //adds the button to the Jframe SplashScreen

    splashImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/Backgroundtests/src/Test1/leagueIMG.png"));
    addComponent(SplashScreen, splashImage, 0,0,1,1);




    SplashScreen.setSize(960,540);  //sets the size of the window
    SplashScreen.setResizable(false);
    SplashScreen.setVisible(true);  //sets the panel visibility to true
    SplashScreen.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    SplashScreen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);




    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent argO)
        {
            //new Window(); 
            SplashScreen.setVisible(false); //closes the window after the button has been clicked so it doesnt run in the background
        }

    });
}

}
```

Comment: In order to help you, it would be better for you to show your attempt. This way we can see what you might be doing wrong, what assumptions that you have that may be incorrect, and thus offer better help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Create a class that extends JPanel
- Draw your image inside of this class's `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method using the Graphics method, `g.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, null)`
- Don't forget to call the `super.paintComponent(g)` method first thing in your paintComponent override.
- Set this JPanel's layout to GridBagLayout if desired.
- When adding to GridBagLayout, create a GridBagConstraints object and add your component *with* the constraints object: `add(myComponent, myGridBagConstraint)`
- If you add another JPanel onto this drawing JPanel, make sure that the added JPanel is not opaque via `addedJPanel.setOpaque(false)`. This way the image displayed in the container JPanel will show through the added JPanel.

For example the code below creates this GUI:

[image: Background Image in GUI]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ShowBackgroundImage {
   public static final String IMAGE_PATH = "https://duke.kenai.com/glassfish/GlassFishMedium.jpg";

   private static void createAndShowUI() {
      Image image = null;
      try {
         URL url = new URL(IMAGE_PATH);
         image = ImageIO.read(url);
         // JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
         ImagePanelA imagePanel = new ImagePanelA(image);

         JFrame frame = new JFrame("Big Duke Image");
         frame.getContentPane().add(imagePanel);
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.pack();
         frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         frame.setVisible(true);
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowUI();
         }
      });
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class ImagePanelA extends JPanel {
   private Image image;

   public ImagePanelA(Image image) {
      this.image = image;
      setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

      add(new JButton("Monday"), createGbc(0, 0, 1, 1));
      add(new JButton("Tuesday"), createGbc(1, 0, 1, 1));
      add(new JButton("Wednesday"), createGbc(0, 1, 1, 1));
      add(new JButton("Thursday"), createGbc(1, 1, 1, 1));
   }

   private GridBagConstraints createGbc(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.gridx = x;
      gbc.gridy = y;
      gbc.gridwidth = w;
      gbc.gridheight = h;

      gbc.weightx = 0.0; // bunches stuff in center in x orientation
      gbc.weighty = 0.0; // bunches stuff in center in y orientation
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
      gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

      return gbc;
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      Dimension superSize = super.getPreferredSize();
      if (isPreferredSizeSet() || image == null) {
         return superSize;
      }
      int prefW = Math.max(image.getWidth(null), superSize.width);
      int prefH = Math.max(image.getHeight(null), superSize.height);
      return new Dimension(prefW, prefH);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      if (image != null) {
         g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
      }
   }
}
```